# Config webpack encore for symfony

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, webpack, assets, webpack-encore

I have created a symfony project.
For manage the js and the css I use webpack encore as advised in symfony official.
And in dev environment, everyhting works well.
yarn run encore dev create correct  path for my asset.

An example of my html

```
link href="{{ asset('build/page-connexion/connexion.css') }}"
```

the request URL for that is

> http://localhost:8000/build/footer/footer.css

But in production when I run "yarn run encore production"
the path is not correct
the request url for the footer is

> http://mydomain.fr/build/footer/footer.css

it should be http://mydomain.fr/mywebsite/public/build/footer/footer.css

How and where can I configure this path? in my HTACCESS?

I know that if I change setPublicPath('myfullpath') with the path of my server in the webpack.config.js it will works. But logically i don't have to change it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: http://mydomain.fr/build/footer/footer.css is correct, "public" directory is supposed to be your document root.

Comment: Yes Orange18947 but so how can i set public my document root in prod ?

Comment: By configuring your web server https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

`public` is root directory for your webserver. And if you configured `setOutputPath` and `setPublicPath` in webpack.config.js you need just add `link href="{{ asset('your_entry_point.css') }}"` to html code. Also you can check `entrypoints.json` this file will contain all paths for your entrypoints.